# ksh if statement syntax

Tags: ksh

I have this `if` statement and every time I change something another thing seems to be wrong. Can you see the problem?

```
if [[ $(ps -ef | grep "Process" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}') = '' ]]; then
        echo "bien"
fi
```

I get `launcher.sh[74]: 11927676^J15335522: syntax error`

Comment: I guess you are missing the $ in (ps. It should be $(ps.
Also add what you have tried and the errors you are having to the question.

Comment: it doesn't work.. :(

Answer (score 2):

If "Process" is a fixed string, try

```
ps -ef | awk '/[p]rocess/ {print $2}'
```

to get process id.

If you are checking for a missing process ( ... = '' )

```
if ps -ef | grep -q [P]rocess
then 
   echo Process present
else
   echo Process absent
fi
```

You might also have a look at `pgrep(1)` (e.g. `man pgrep` )

Answer (score 0):

Comparison in KSH needs to be done with two equal signs. `==`

```
if [[ $(ps -ef | grep "Process" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}') == '' ]]; then
        echo "bien"
fi
```